# How to switch on/off logging using Log4net

Tags: log4net

I have logged all my applications transaction using Log4net. Is there any way I can disable and enable logging from a common place without altering the code written for logging.

Comment: Do you mean like in the app.config?

Answer (score 11):

I assume you want to toggle logging in your running application through code. I did not try it but I think that calling the following method should disable logging:

```
LogManager.GetRepository().ResetConfiguration();
```

To re-enable logging you would call

```
XmlConfigurator.Configure();
```

(or one of the other methods of the `XmlConfigurator`).

However there seems to be an [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4NET-198) with calling the `Configure` method repeatedly. I do not know if this would be a problem for you, but at least I warned you...

Comment: +1 Unlike the other responses, this one closes files that the logger holds open.

Answer (score 11):

You can turn them off by changing the log4net config file. Specifically change the appender's level or global level to "OFF" value. See [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/introduction.html) for details

Comment: Log levels are defined on the logger, not the appender. Appenders may use level filters. It can also be that a root logger has level OFF but a child logger still logs something.

Comment: Yep, sure, but the idea is still make it through a config file, not code.

Comment: Fair enough. It is my impression though that this is not what the OP is asking for...

Answer (score 2):

Assuming I understand your question, from the FAQ: http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html

How do I completely disable all logging at runtime?

Setting the Threshold on the Hierarchy to Level OFF will disable all logging from that Hierarchy. This can be done in the log4net configuration file by setting the "threshold" attribute on the log4net configuration element to "OFF". For example: